Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DraggableProps', NEXTJS/ React
I'm using @hello-pangea/dnd (react-beautiful-dnd fork) to create a drag and drop list.
The thing is that, I'm using this custom prop
<Draggable draggableId={section.id} index={index} type="section">
//type <- new/ custom prop

But, it doesn't exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DraggableProps'.
Because of this error, I cannot build the app, but, what I've managed to do, is to add this into type
type DraggableChildrenFn = (provided: DraggableProvided, snapshot: DraggableStateSnapshot, rubic: DraggableRubric) => ReactNode | null;
interface DraggableProps {
    draggableId: DraggableId;
    index: number;
    children: DraggableChildrenFn;
    isDragDisabled?: boolean;
    disableInteractiveElementBlocking?: boolean;
    shouldRespectForcePress?: boolean;
    type?: string; <- this type
}

The app now builds, locally, but on Vercel, I still get that error.
What I've tried to do was, to add to github the path to the dnd types node_modules\.pnpm\@hello-pangea+dnd@16.6.0_@types+react-dom@18.2.24_@types+react@18.2.74_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\@hello-pangea\dnd\dist\dnd.d.ts
I've managed to add it to repo, but, on vercel, it's downloading the package again, and I assume it's overlapping it.
Another thing I've tried was to create an interface that extends the props type, but it doesn't work...
I want to keep that type prop, because, I'm using the component twice for 2 separate things, and this allows me to track where do I do modifications.
    if (type === "section") {
      handleSectionDragDrop(source, destination, updatedSections);
    } else {
      handleTaskDragDrop(source, destination, updatedSections);
    }


What is your goal? Passing a "custom" prop to a 3rd party component that doesn't use that prop won't do anything, so what is your actual objective here?

I'm using the component twice, one for sections, and one for task. The props let's me track which component I move, so I can reorder them.
if (type === "section") {
handleSectionDragDrop(source, destination, updatedSections);
} else {
handleTaskDragDrop(source, destination, updatedSections);
}

Managed to do a workaround:
Instead of:
<Droppable droppableId={section.id} type="task">

I did:
<Droppable droppableId={`task|${section.id}`}>

then, i could use the type:
const type = result.droppableId.split('|')[0]

